# SQL lookup & like - how to combine them?

Tags: sql, lookup, sql-like, qlikview

I have two tables.
The first one called "Project" includes *project names* and *project short names* like e.g. 'abc', 'def', 'xyz' etc.
The second table "Contracts" contains *project names* and *purchase orders* that in their name include a project short name, sometimes more than one e.g. 109abc367, 199gDEF or ABC100_XYZ, sometimes none, e.g. 19762. One PO can be for more than one project just as well as for none (e.g. lab equipment).
What I need is to create a field or another table which would be connected to both "Project" as well as "Contract" and if I, say, select 'abc' in *project short names*, it would show me all entries from *purchase orders* that include 'abc' or 'ABC', all that in Qlikview. Since the number of projects is huge and they change dynamically, I can't do that manually for every each one.
I thought about the `lookup` function but does it go with `like` at all? Is there any way to achieve that at all? I would be very grateful for ideas.

EDIT:

```
Project:
LOAD Project_Names,
     Project_Short_Names //abc, klm, xyz etc.
FROM
xyz.csv //a dynamic table derived from SAP



Contracts:
LOAD Project_Names,
     Purchase_Orders  //possible entries: 109abc367, 199gDEF, ABC100_XYZ, 19762
FROM
abcd.csv //another SAP derived table, different one than the previous one, 
         //impossible to combine them
```

What I need:
a possibility (field, extra table..?) to sort for me entries from `Purchase_Orders` based on the entries in `Project_Short_Names`. E.g. if I select 'abc' in `Project_Short_Names`, I get all entries from `Purchase_Orders` that include 'abc' or 'ABC'.

Currently the two tables are connected by the field `Project_Names`, and once I select 'abc' in `Project_Short_Names`, as a result I get not only entries including 'abc' but also these that do not include any project short names, e.g. PO '19762' - the reason why is because e.g. lab equipment theoretically belongs to all projects, yet this time I want to exclude it.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, most likely you don't need a `function` for that. From your description it sound like the another table with relation to `Project` should be enough. But to be able to suggests something specific we need to have some playground, maybe even a fiddle. Please proper one (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Another point is about using `like` for filtering against something in the middle (like in `like '%abc%'` which may be quite slow.